# Showing a jsp in a loop till user enters a correct value

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I am quite new to web programming. So, here is what my problem is
I want user to enter a number on HTML and my servlet has some logic to check if the number is correct I show ajsp with one msg if not then other msg. So, this part is quite simple and i achieved it easily. But my problem is that I want to keep on doing this. So, I want once user see result.jsp. He should be directed back to form.html but with different background color. 
So I tried something like this in my jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Passing the input value to a session variable</title>
  <%
    String bgColor = request.getParameter("COLOR");

      if (bgColor == null)
         bgColor = "WHITE";
  %>
</head>
<body BGCOLOR="<%=bgColor%>">
   <%
    String msg = (String) session.getAttribute("message");
    out.print(msg);
%>
<a href="login.html"> <input type="submit" value="Try again!!"
    name="TRY">
</a>
```

This one redirects me to login.html but the color is lost. How can i pass background color to login.html so that background color is changed.

Please some suggestions. 
Thanks

Comment: Where is the relevant html that allows user to input number? Also is this some homework or is it mandate for you to use jsp and servlets only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set color as a parameter to href

```
<a href="login.html?color='<%=bgColor%>'">
     <input type="submit" value="Try again!!" name="TRY">
</a>
```

Comment: It Worked. Thank u soooo much .